# PDO connection to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have done this once before in a VM, however, I needed to create a second instance of a VM, and I am trying to connect to my MS SQL Server. Currently I have `php-5.3.6-nts-Win32-VC9-x86` version of php installed. I have correctly configured my `php.ini` and running `phpinfo()` I can verify that I have sqlsqrv PDO drivers installed correctly. I am using this in conjunction with IIS 7, and I have the webserver up and running. I have the following line in my `index.php` file

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName; Database=classReg");
```

I also have the following to give me some feedback on if I made a successful connection to the database.

```
if($conn) {
    echo "Connection established. </br></br>";
} else {
    echo "Connection could not be established. </br>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Problem is, I'm not getting anything out of my $conn variable. I've tried to echo that variable, and I'm not getting any feedback.

FWIW my  `php.ini` file reads these three lines at the end of the file

```
[PHP_MS_SQL_PDO]
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
```

Any ideas as to what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by doing the following:

- I created a user to access the database with in place of Windows Authentication.
- I also added `IUSR` to the database logins group.

After doing those two things, I modified the following line of code to connect to the database.

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName; Database=classReg");
```

This line now reads:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName; Database=classReg", "<user>", "<password>");
```

One thing that helped me out was looking at the logs for the server. I was having an issue, because I wasn't getting any output from my if statement in the original code. But I was able to look at the logs from SQL Server, and I was able to see what was happening. The logs are located at `Management -> SQL Server Logs`. After I made those two changes, I was able to successfully connect to the database without any troubles. I hope this helps anyone else that is running into an issue like this!